# Yearly line rental - moving provider or moving house

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts

I am confused with how paying for a yearly line rental works. As you could guess, I am 12 months into my broadband contract and they are offering me to pay for another years line rental up front. I have two questions about this.

1. If I pay for the 12 months line rental, then decide to change provider after 6 months, does my line rental change with it, even though a paid through plusnet? If so, is this money just deducted from my new contract?
2. If I were to move house, then either change provider or stick with plusnet, does my line rental move with me?

Changing provider or moving house could both happen in the next 12 months, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

1. If you're paying for 12 months line rental as a lump sum payment, and then leave for another provider within that 12 months, then they will keep your money.  You will lose any remaining months.  You will have to pay the new provider for the service.
2. Again, this will be in the contract.  Usually, you can take the service with you.  The service just carries on for the remainder of the contracted period.  Check what happens if they are unable to provide the service at the new address.  The terms may also be different if the provider has to install a new line at the new property.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for I'm afraid. My contract is 18 months long with plusnet for £5 a month. I am talking about LINE RENTAL. Thanks for your response though

Comment: @George I have edited the answer.